# Keyboard shortcut key to send ajax button click

Tags: ajax

Is it possible to write a script to assign certain keyboard shortcut keys to automate the clicking of buttons on an ajax-enabled website? I am not the programmer of the website, just a user.

I am trying out Autohotkey but failed. Any better suggestion?

Comment: you can use tampermonkey for chrom or greasemonkey for firefox, then you need to input code to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use Mousetrap

Mousetrap is a simple library for handling keyboard shortcuts in Javascript. The codes are as simple as these:

```
// single keys
Mousetrap.bind('4', function() { highlight(2); });
Mousetrap.bind('x', function() { highlight(3); }, 'keyup');
```

#### More info: http://craig.is/killing/mice